# Populate a checkbox front of each row and send checked/non-checked values and IDs using json and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want design page like this

[image]

up to now I have created like this . I want to know bind check-box front of each row and send those checked/non-checked values with IDs using json and jquery

[image]

this last code snippet of that page

```
<div style="width:50%; float:left;text-align:left"><button id="resetborchure" type="button" class="btn btn-warning submit">Reset Brochure</button> </div>
<div style="width:50%; float:left;text-align:right"><button id="createborchure" type="button" class="btn btn-danger submit">Create Brochure</button> </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>

    @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")




        <script type="text/javascript">

            var url = '@Url.Action("FetchProductProperties")';
            var editUrl = '@Url.Action("Edit")';

            var type = $('#Type');
            var category = $('#Category');
            var country = $('#Country');
            var product = $('#Product');


            var template = $('#template');
            var table = $('#table');
            $('#search').click(function () {
                table.empty();
                $.getJSON(url, { type: type.val(), category: category.val(), country: country.val(), product: product.val() }, function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                        var clone = template.clone();
                        var cells = clone.find('td');
                        cells.eq(0).text(item.ID);
                        cells.eq(1).text(item.Name);
                        table.append(clone.find('tr'));
                    });
                });
            });

            $('#resetborchure').click(function () {
                table.empty();
            });

        </script>


    }
```

Also I want , once I checked and click create brochure button I want  send those checked/non-checked values with IDs using json

I have try to put to populate a checkbox with each listed result `'<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>'` inside `cells.eq(1).text(item.Name);`

as `cells.eq(1).text('<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>'+item.Name);` but this is not working

Once I click "Select Information" button Its list down data from `AB_Product_Property` table , IF I want to populate check-box with each search result row Do I need maintain boolean field in that table also ?? I want to do this without maintain column for that boolean field in `AB_Product_Property` table

Comment: You don't need a boolean field in the database, you need it in your view model

Comment: okay I added in view model as `public Nullable<System.Boolean> IsChecked { get; set; }` but then how to bind within script 
`cells.eq(1).checkbox(item.IsChecked)` or `cells.eq(1).string(item.IsChecked)` ?

Comment: No, you need a `bool` for each item (and not nullable) - You need a view model say (`IncludeVM`) with `int ID`, `string Name` and `bool IsSelected`, and then in you main view model a property `List<IncludeVM> Options` Then use a `for` loop to render `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Options[i].ID` and `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Options[i].IsSelected` and you can simply use `$('form').serialize()` to post back everything

Comment: since I need required field I decided to add Boolean field , then how can I handle this ? without using razor syntax how to bind this in `cells.eq(1).____(_____)`

Comment: Whats _I need required field_ got to do with it? And why are you not wanting to use razor? And why do you want to write extra jquery code?

Comment: once its filtered I want to show checked some results by default, since this is json call I thought it will better populate checkbox field using extra jquery code

Comment: Your making an ajax call so you stay on the same page. If you select say 2 of those checkboxes, then when the ajax call is complete, the same 3 checkboxes are still selected.

Comment: Actually I'm an infant to these technologies, I cant understand what you said could you please explain more

Comment: I have added an answer explaining how to use a view model to do this and also how you can post back the view model simply using the jquery `.serialize()` function

Comment: Currently I created it like this https://dotnetfiddle.net/ycxlN2  if I have to switch to your approach do I need to remove all the `FetchProductProperties` json script

Answer (score 1):

Create a view model(s) to represent what you want to display/edit.

```
public class OptionsVM
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}

public class SearchVM
{
  public int Asset { get; set; }
  public SelectList AssetList { get; set; }
  public int Category{ get; set; }
  public SelectList CategoryList { get; set; }
  .... // other properties and SelectLists for the dropdownlists
  public List<OptionsVM> Options { get; set; }
}
```

and in the GET method, populate the Options with the `ID` and `Name` properties

Then in the view

```
@model SearchVM
....
<form>
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Asset, Model.AssetList)
  ....
  @for(int i = 0; i < Model.Options.Count; i++)
  {
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Options[i].ID)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Options[i].IsSelected)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Options[i].IsSelected, Model.Options[i].Name)
  }
<button type="button" id="createbrochure">Create Brochure</button>
```

and in the script

```
$('#createbrochure').click(function () {
  $.getJSON(url, $('form').serialize(), function (data) {
    ....
  });
})
```

and in the controller method

```
public ActionResult CreateBrochure(SearchVM model)
{
  // To get the ID's of all selected options
  IEnumerable<int> selectedOptions = model.Options.Where(o => o.IsSelected).Select(o => o.ID);
  ....
}
```

Comment: Currently I created it like this https://dotnetfiddle.net/ycxlN2, if I have to switch to your approach do I have to remove all the `FetchProductProperties` json script

Comment: another question Can I pass those parameters and values using `Jsonresult` instead of `ActionResult`

Comment: Yes of course - `JsonResult` is `ActionResult` :) (will have a look at the fiddle later)

Comment: Your `FetchProductProperties()` remains the same except that its `FetchProductProperties(SearchVM model)` rather that all the individual parameters you currently have - and you then need to use `.StartsWith(model.Type)` rather than `.StartsWith(type)`

Comment: `FetchProductProperties()` method working fine what i need to use `.StartsWith(type)`rather than `.StartsWith(model.Type)`

Comment: Other way around :). At the moment your passing individual parameters to the method (`string type, string category, etc`). If you now pass back the view model, just now need to access the properties of the model i.e. `model.Type`, `model.Category` etc.

Comment: AS I understood this question have two sections one is populating product property name and its checked or not (Boolean field)  as checked box then second one is , once I click "Create Brochure" button send checked valuse and nonchecked valuse with their relevant ids of those populated result

Comment: Yes, both methods pass back the view model, which includes the values of all the checkboxes.

Comment: actually i dont know how to fetch database valuse as align that as a check box , but I able to align checkbox without bind database field value like this `<td><input type="checkbox" /></td> ` yeah this meaningless, but dont know do this in correct way

Comment: Look at the last code block in my answer - you get all the selected ID values using `model.Options.Where(o => o.IsSelected).Select(o => o.ID)`

Comment: its for 2nd section I think , before that I want to findout a way to populate product property name and its relevant IsChecked Boolean field values as checked box

Comment: It's in my answer! Sorry, but if your not understanding this, then perhaps you need to get someone to write your code for you.

Comment: Actually I tried to do this in many ways one is I try to use `cells.eq(1).checkboxfor(item.CheckOrNot);` then its freezing the seach results non of things list down

Comment: where should I put this  `for loop` code snippet ? withing table or should I use inside form

Comment: Inside the form so that when you use `$('form').serialize()` it sends all the form values (the selected values of the dropdownlists plus all the ID's of the options with a value indicating if they are selected or not. But its a bit unclear what is the difference between the 'Select Information' button and the 'Create Brochure' button (do both methods need the ID's of the selected options?)

Comment: once I select "Select Information" its list-down results in table with following columns "ID" ,"Property_name" according to drop-downs , then I can send , check or uncheck from filtered results pass those values to another controller

Answer (score 0):

You can create new column for check box instead of appending check box to name column.

Than you can set class to that check box and get the checked or unchecked check box value using jquery.

Comment: can I know the syntax